# Changing the order of custom fields in the dashboard for Woocommerce variable products

Tags: php, functions, custom-field, woocommerce-offtopic, variables

I followed this quick/well laid out wordpress tutorial for adding custom fields to WooCommerce variations.

http://www.remicorson.com/woocommerce-custom-fields-for-variations/

Everything worked great...

However the method for inserting the field into the dashboard (product edit) area doesn't mention **how to change the order of the field as seen in the dashboard**.
.
[image]

```
// Add Variation Settings
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes', 'variation_settings_fields', 10, 3 );
// Save Variation Settings
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_variation_settings_fields', 10, 2 );

function variation_settings_fields( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ) {
    // Text Field
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
        array( 
            'id'          => '_text_field[' . $variation->ID . ']', 
            'label'       => __( 'My Text Field', 'woocommerce' ), 
            'placeholder' => 'http://',
            'desc_tip'    => 'true',
            'description' => __( 'Enter the custom value here.', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value'       => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, '_text_field', true )
        )
    );

}

function save_variation_settings_fields( $post_id ) {
    // Text Field
    $text_field = $_POST['_text_field'][ $post_id ];
    if( ! empty( $text_field ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_text_field', esc_attr( $text_field ) );
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meta box template for the variations is defined in the file [html-variation-admin.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/admin/meta-boxes/views/html-variation-admin.php). There you will find the hook *"woocommerce_variation_options_pricing"*. With this hook you can add your input field to the desired place.

```
function variation_settings_fields($loop, $variation_data, $variation)
{
    // Your Text Field
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id' => '_text_field[' . $variation->ID . ']',
            'label' => __('My Text Field', 'woocommerce'),
            'placeholder' => 'http://',
            'wrapper_class' => 'form-row',
            'desc_tip' => 'true',
            'description' => __('Enter the custom value here.', 'woocommerce'),
            'value' => get_post_meta($variation->ID, '_text_field', true)
        )
    );
}

add_action('woocommerce_variation_options_pricing','variation_settings_fields');
```

[image: WooCommerce variations meta box with the custome field between price and the stock field]